# insert value to an input tag in a php file

Tags: android

How do you insert a value inside an input box from a php file?

for example i have this code

```
<h1><a>App Test Form</a></h1>
        <form id="form_6" class="digitalfuture"  method="post" action="#main_body">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>App Test Form</h2>
            <p></p>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_8" >
        <label class="description">Name <span id="required_8" class="required">*</span></label>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_1" name= "element_8_1" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value="hello" />
            <label>First</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_8_2" name= "element_8_2" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value="" />
            <label>Last</label>
        </span><p class="guidelines" id="guide_8"><small>Please tell us your name</small></p> 
        </li>
```

can anyone point out any tutorials that can help me?

Comment: what does it has to do with android?

Comment: Aye, this has to do with php and html, not with anything of an android machine. and what do you want exactly in the input box. The value what has been shot back out of the database, or just a random text, you made up, such as "enter here your name here?" The last one is achieved by adding in the brackets from your input the 'placeholder' atrtibute. The first one can be picked up from the database and be put there in the input field itself. It's then put in the 'value' atribute you can put in the element

Comment: well this is a part of a large app i made, where database is involve and other stuff, the main function is the user use the app and after he/she is finished he/she can press a button to send all the info and items inside the app to a remote server and fill a form automatically which will be view automatically by the admin

Comment: @Dorvalla yes I can just use php and html but there are calculations involved where users are not familiar with so I made things easy for them using android devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

source.php:

```
<?php
    $data = 'text';
?>
```

input.php:

```
<?php
    include('source.php');
    echo '<input type="text" name="example" value="', $data, '" />';
?>
```

That will insert the contents of $data into the input field value.

Or did you mean something else?

If you want the text to be visible directly when the page is opened, you can use the html5 feature "placeholder" in the input tag. Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="example" placeholder="Write your comment" />
```

That will show an input field in the page with the text "Write your comment" visible in the field until the user clicks on it and/or writes to the field (no need to delete the placeholder text manually, it disappears automatically).

So when you combine them, it would look like this:

source.php:

```
<?php
    $data = 'text';
?>
```

input.php:

```
<?php
    include('source.php');
    echo '<input type="text" name="example" placeholder="', $data, '" />';
?>
```

Comment: the android device should be the one responsible sending the data to the webpage, not the php script